# Shortening code or making code more concise for my calculator?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make the code that generates my buttons shorter? Can someone show me how to do it? Any ideas?

```
    Clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="C", width=7, height=1, command=self.clear, relief=RAISED)
    Clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=0)
    Equals = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="=", width=7, height=1, command=self.equals, relief=RAISED)
    Equals.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=3)
    All_clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="AC", width=7, height=1, command=self.all_clear, relief=RAISED)
    All_clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=0)
    Bracket_one = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="(", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_one, relief=RAISED)
    Bracket_one.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=2, row=3)
    Bracket_two = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=")", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_two, relief=RAISED)
    Bracket_two.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=3)
    Zero = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="0", width=7, height=1, command=self.zero, relief=RAISED)
    Zero.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=0, row=3)
    Decimal_point = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=".", width=7, height=1, command=self.decimal_point, relief=RAISED)
    Decimal_point.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=1, row=3)
    Multiplication = Button(buttons, bg="red", text="x", width=7, height=1, command=self.multiplication, relief=RAISED)
    Multiplication.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=1)
    Division = Button(buttons, bg="powder blue", text="/", width=7, height=1, command=self.division, relief=RAISED)
    Division.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=1)
    Addition = Button(buttons, bg="yellow", text="+", width=7, height=1, command=self.addition, relief=RAISED)
    Addition.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=2)
    Subtraction = Button(buttons, bg="green", text="-", width=7, height=1, command=self.subtraction, relief=RAISED)
    Subtraction.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=2)
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

Use a list with parameters:

```
buttons = [
    dict(column=3, row=0, text="C", command=self.clear),
    dict(column=4, row=3, text="=", command=self.equals),
    dict(column=4, row=0, text="AC", command=self.all_clear),
    dict(column=2, row=3, text="(", command=self.bracket_one),
    dict(column=3, row=3, text=")", command=self.bracket_two),
]
for data in buttons:
    button = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=data['text'], width=7, height=1, command=data['command'], relief=RAISED)
    button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=data['column'], row=data['row'])
```

Comment: Why not just unpack each `dict` with `**`?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to name that list of dicts `buttons`, since that appears to be the OP's root widget for the Button grid.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Because some of the fields need to be passed to the `Button` constructor and some of them need to be passed to the button's `.grid` method.

Comment: @PM2Ring - then maybe a separate `dict` for each of those, and store each pair in a `tuple` or `dict`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: this increases the complexity on the definition side, but does not decrease it considerably on the execution side. That `**` exists does not mean, you have to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As a modified alternative to Daniel's solution:

```
buttons = [
    ({'text':"C", 'command':self.clear}, {'column':3, 'row':0}),
    ({'text':"=", 'command':self.equals}, {'column':4, 'row':3}),
    ({'text':"AC", 'command':self.all_clear}, {'column':4, 'row':0}),
    ({'text':"(", 'command':self.bracket_one}, {'column':2, 'row':3}),
    ({'text':")", 'command':self.bracket_two}, {'column':3, 'row':3})
]
for data in buttons:
    button = Button(buttons, width=7, height=1, relief=RAISED, **data[0])
    button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, **data[1])
```

This will grab the appropriate dictionary and unpack its contents into keyword arguments. One benefit of this is that you can add, say, a `bitmap` to one of the buttons without needing to add one to the others.